# Java mySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

Basically i'm just checking to see if a player exists in a mySQL database, but it keeps throwing errors and such. I'm not sure how to go about doing it. 
(This is all done in the bukkit api, the problem is just SQL though)

When the player logs in it will call the databaseFindPlayer method to see if they exist in the database

All I need to see is if the player exists in the database or not

```
 @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerLogin(PlayerJoinEvent e) throws SQLException {
        getLogger().info("Player joining.... + TEST");
        if (databaseFindPlayer(e.getPlayer().getName()) == false) {
            getLogger().info("Player does not have data file.. Generating one now");
            databaseCreatePlayer(e.getPlayer().getName());
            databaseFindPlayer(e.getPlayer().getName()); //For debugging
        }
    }





  public boolean databaseFindPlayer(String name) throws SQLException {
            getLogger().info("finding players");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement("show columns from players where field = '" + name + "';");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, name);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("Player exists!");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player doesn't exist!");
                return false;
            }


    }
```

(All the getLogger() calls where for debugging)

Edit:

```
Error message
[18:14:17 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to CustomLeaderboard v0.1

org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
va:294) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.jav
a:62) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
ava:501) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
ava:486) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.c(PlayerList.java:251) [craft
bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:138) [craft
bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:76) [
craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.LoginListener.a(LoginListener.java:42) [
craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:160
) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:134) [craf
tbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:6
67) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:2
58) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:5
58) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:469) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:6
28) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of pa
rameters, which is 0).
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) ~[craf
tbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) ~[craft
bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982) ~[craft
bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927) ~[craft
bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3
709) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3
693) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:454
4) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        at com.mcaletheia.customLeaderboard.CustomLeaderboard.databaseFindPlayer
(CustomLeaderboard.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at com.mcaletheia.customLeaderboard.CustomLeaderboard.onPlayerLogin(Cust
omLeaderboard.java:69) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0
_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1
.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
va:292) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-24-g07d4558-b3116jnks]
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling exactly what is wrong

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Taking a look back the code you are declaring the statement using

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement("show columns from players where field = '" + name + "';");
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
```

But you've provided no parameters to which you can bind your value

Instead, it should be

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement("show columns from players where field = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
```

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: So just to be clear, the ? signifies a variable in SQL that is passed to name?

Comment: Yes, but think of it more like a parameter, like a method method, the `?` defines an exception for a parameter which you use the `set` methods to provide, so they need to be set in the correct order ;)

Comment: A new problem, when a player logs into the server but already has a place in the database it still returns false and generates another one.

Comment: Your query probably should be `select count(*) from players where field = ?` assuming that the column name is correct.  You could then need to extract the result from the `ResultSet` and check the return value (count)

Comment: How would I check count and use it so see if the player has already been entered in the database?

Comment: Start with the basics, `if (rs.next())`, if this returns `false`, then something went wrong with the query, otherwise you should be able to use `rs.getLong(0)` will return the result of the `count` function

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the intent of the `PreparedStatement` class here.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement("show columns from players where field = '" + name + "';");
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
```

By saying `setString(1, name)`, you are saying "Set the first replacement in the query to whatever is in the field called `name`". Since your query doesn't have any replacments, it is complaining about that. (Parameter index out of range). It knows you have zero parameters and you are telling it you have one.

Try this instead (note, I've also removed the semicolon at the end of your query):

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement("show columns from players where field = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
```

Another way you could solve this is by not setting the name argument at all, but by inserting a possibly tainted value manually you are opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack. Stick with the `?` replacement outlined above.